# Do I need NULL values in SQL table for IDs that don't exist

Tags: mysql

I have an MySQL application that has many-to-many relationships.  My main table is my materials table.  In all of my other tables I have a `material_id` to match the table ID.  So in my supplier table, I have `supplier_id` and `material_id.`

For this application, some materials do not have suppliers.  For my SQL `SELECT` statement to return correctly that there are no suppliers for that material, should I have an entry of NULL for that `supplier_id` to match the `material_id`?  Or will the SQL `JOIN` statement not return a result and I can script that accordingly in my PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even create a `NULL` entry for the mapping.

You need an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins), something like

```
select * from materials m left outer join suppliers s on (m.material_id=s.material_id);
```

It will return null values for the suppliers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to populate `NULL`s. What you want is an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins). From Wikipedia:

> The result of a left outer join (or
>   simply left join) for table A and B
>   always contains all records of the
>   "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any
>   matching record in the "right" table
>   (B). This means that if the ON clause
>   matches 0 (zero) records in B, the
>   join will still return a row in the
>   result—but with NULL in each column
>   from B. This means that a left outer
>   join returns all the values from the
>   left table, plus matched values from
>   the right table (or NULL in case of no
>   matching join predicate).

Answer (score -1):

> ...should I have an entry of NULL for
>   that supplier_id to match the
>   material_id? Or will the SQL JOIN
>   statement not return a result and I
>   can script that accordingly in my PHP?

Both. Neither.

The meaning of "null" is "I have no information on this". If there is no supplier, the logical thing to do is to leave the column "null".

However, given that you're talking about a "join table" representing a many-to-many relationship, the best thing is not to insert a record in the join table at all. After all, logically, the absence of the record shows there is no relationship to suppliers.

You may need an outer join to make it all work when querying, though...

Comment: I would not advise putting NULL as an id in a mapping to indicate that one side of the relation is not statisfied. That is dirty and unecessary data. A row in the mapping should only exist if a supplier really exists.

Comment: Quite right - I didn't read it properly. If it's "many to many", just don't put a record in the relation table.